# mount block device as /var/log during startup

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, block-device

I would like to use the ram block device to store the contents of `/var/log` folder.  The ram-backed block device driver I used is the same one as in this [link](http://opensourceforu.com/2012/02/device-drivers-disk-on-ram-block-drivers/).

This one creates the device `/dev/rb`. I would like to know what I need to do in order to: (1) format it as ext3fs, and (2) mount it as `/var/log`. This needs to be done during the system startup.

Successful test: various kernel messages files are stored in the ram device I created.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should all be doable in the [`/etc/rc.local`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/8/rc.local/) startup file, which gets run at the end of every runlevel.

To mount onto /var/log, you will need to stop any process that has files open in the log directory, mount and then restart them. My suggestion would be to add the following line to your `rc.local` script, so it runs at boot:

```
    lsof | grep /var/log | awk '{ print $1 }' | uniq > /root/logs_open
```

`lsof` lists all open files. We then filter out all lines that don't reference /var/log (`grep /var/log`). We print only the first column (process name) of the result (`awk '{ print $1 }'`), keeping only one copy of each (`uniq`) and sending the output to a file (`> /root/logs_open`). You will have to add something to the startup file to stop these processes before mounting the partition, and restart them afterwords. With this information in hand, remove that line from rc.local, and we can begin.

First, we need to do whatever you need to so the ramdisk is created. Maybe you make a script to do this.

```
/root/create_ramdisk.sh
```

To make an ext3 file system, you run:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/rb
```

Next, stop any process that is logging.

```
service apache2 stop
```

Now we can mount onto /var/log

```
mount /dev/rb /var/log
```

Start back up the processes we stopped earlier

```
service apache2 start
```

Finally, rc.local must exit with 0 status or Bad Things™ happen.

```
exit 0
```

`rc.local` script:

```
/root/create_ramdisk.sh # example purposes only
mkfs.ext3 /dev/rb # create the filesystem
system apache2 stop # stop processes with open log files
mount /dev/rb /var/log # mount
system apache2 start # restart anything we stopped before
exit 0 # important!!! rc.local must exit successfully or Bad Things (tm) happen
```

I hope this helps.